# How to call outer function from inner function in nodejs? I am coding for Google dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, dialogflow-es

1. Hello friends, Help me out for coding `dialogflow` fulfillment.
2. here is the code where i'm invoking GET Api in inner request module and i want to api's output into outer function in `conv.ask('Sales is 1 million metric tonnes ' + b)`

***Code:***

```
var request = require('request');
var code1 = null;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');

const assistant = dialogflow({
    clientId: "305xxxx407-rv9kocdxxxxxxxxxciouuq8f9ul2eg.apps.googleusercontent.com"
});

module.exports = (app) => {
        const logger = console;
        assistant.intent('Sales', (conv) => {
            const baseurl = 'https://www.ixxxxxxt.in:3500/getunits?unitcode=4';
            var a = request(baseurl, function(error, res, body) {
                var Unit = JSON.parse(body);
                if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
                    var code = JSON.stringify(Unit.description);
                    //res.render(test(Unit));
                    console.log(code); // Print the google web page.
                }
            })
            var b = (a.code);
            console.log(b);
            conv.ask('Sales is 1 million metric tonnes ' + b);
        })
```

Comment: Simply place `conv.ask` inside the `request` callback function. Or use async/await.

Comment: Its not working. can roughly elaborate in code? as i am beginner it will me great help for me. thanks @Molda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here.

The first is understanding what `request()` is doing. You probably don't want what `request()` returns, but instead want access to the `body`, which you get from the function you define.

That function is actually the second parameter that you've passed to `request()`. It is referred to as the *callback function*, since when `request()` gets the data from the URL, it will call that function. So everything you want to do with `body` needs to be done inside the callback function.

However, since you're using the Dialogflow library, and this is being done inside an Intent Handler, you need to return a Promise to indicate that you're waiting for a result before it can reply to the user. While you *can* wrap `request()` in a Promise, there are better solutions, most notably using the [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) package, which is very similar to the request package, but uses Promises.

This makes things a *lot* easier. Your code might look something more like this (untested):

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');
var code1 = null;
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');

const assistant = dialogflow({
    clientId: "305xxxx407-rv9kocdxxxxxxxxxciouuq8f9ul2eg.apps.googleusercontent.com"
});

module.exports = (app) => {
    const logger = console;
    assistant.intent('Sales', (conv) => {
        const baseurl = 'https://www.ixxxxxxt.in:3500/getunits?unitcode=4';
        return request(baseurl)
            .then( body => {
                // You don't need the body parser anymore
                let code = body.description;
                conv.ask('Sales is 1 million metric tonnes ' + code);
            })
            .catch( err => {
                console.error( err );
                conv.ask('Something went wrong. What should I do now?');
            });
    })
```